# A website that performs a similar function to Firebug, Chrome developer tools etc

Tags: css, dom, firebug, saas

I'm looking for a website that duplicates at least some of the most basic features of Firebug, Chrome developer tools, etc, but that is simple enough for a non-developer to use.

At the very least, I want to be able to tell a non-developer to:

1. Visit http://checkthedom.com/sitethatneedschecking.com
2. Hover over a particular paragraph of text or some other element
3. Tell me font etc is used in that element

I need to find a web site that does this because I can't ask the non-developers to use bookmarklets or install browser plug-ins or to follow instructions that will vary depending on what particular browser they are using.

I've pasted an image below that shows what I want the non-developers to see.

Is there a website that does this?

[image]

Comment: This sounds highly specific for _your_ needs. Who's to say other people wouldn't require other information? Colours, positioning etc. Before long, you've just got Firebug. Having said that, if it doesn't exist, you should build it. I'm sure it would still be a pretty popular tool!

Comment: If the site did all that firebug does, that would be great. I just didn't want people to avoid mentioning a potential site because it only did some of what firebug does.

Comment: Hmm I just gave it a shot, but it's probably going to be a real struggle. To load up another site on your domain, you'd need to use an iframe. And if you do that, you can't execute any js on the child frame. Bummer! A bookmarket, unfortunately for you, probably is the best option. I built a [tiny example using jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/YufVv/), if you converted it to pure ps you could make a relatively small bookmarket that should solve the job.

Comment: Thanks Christian. There are loads of cool bookmarklets. I'll have another think about how I can walk non-developers through the process of using them. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of sites I've tried do this:

- [XRAY](http://westciv.com/xray/)
- [X-Ray Goggles](http://hackasaurus.org/en-US/goggles/)

Although it doesn't show the CSS as a popup (it's on the right hand side of the window), the Firefox [built-in 3D viewer](https://superuser.com/questions/401005/how-to-enable-the-new-3d-page-inspector-view-in-firefox-11) might help visualise the site.

Comment: Thanks. Bookmarklets like XRAY were my inspiration. But I'm looking for a way to achieve this without asking non-developers to install a bookmarklet. Thanks again.